# Excel SUMIF with exact word but not case sensitive match

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I have a simplified table for this problem example

```
Column A       |  Column B  |  Column C

war            | 1          | war

War            | 2

warred         | 3 

war and peace  | 4

awful war      | 5

dead war horse | 6
```

Now I need to find all rows containing the word "war" that is not case sensitive, but must be a separate word, not a part of another word.

For example

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6;"C1";B1:B6)
```

right now finds only values "war" and "War" and SUM is 3.

I want it to find also values "war and peace", "awful war" and "dead war horse" since they all contain the word "war" and the SUM value should be 18.

I can't use search term

```
"*war*"
```

since this also includes the value "warred" and this is a separate word and shouldn't match.

One possibility is to create 4 different SUMIF-s with terms

```
war
war_*
*_war
*_war_*

_ is space
```

and then sum those four, but this is not that elegant.

I thought SUMPRODUCT with EXACT would work, but this seems to work over columns, not rows and EXACT isn't suitable..it think.

**Is there a way to match row based on word that is not case sensitive and then sum all the values in Column B that have a matching row?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&C1&" "," "&A1:A6&" ")))*B1:B6)

Comment: thanks, didn't even think about adding spaces to the original.